# Deploying postgresql driver dependency with Keycloak SPI jar inside Docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, wildfly, keycloak

When we deploy the custom SPI Jar inside keycloak docker image, we get the ClassNotFoundException for postgresql Driver.

We tried the following, yet got the same error:

1. Adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml with postgresql as module inside opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/org/postgresql/jdbc/main/
   this contains both postgresql.jar and module.xml
2. Using standalone keycloak following the steps as in (module approach) https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_providers_admin_console

But we get the error **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver**

How else can the postgresql dependency used by the jar  can be deployed inside keycloak docker image?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue of Postgresql driver dependency missing issue by generating a fat jar with all dependencies bundled with it.
Followed the link
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html